# Display Random URL inside iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I want to display random url inside iframe, Iframe should load one random url when user land on page. when next user came on landing page it should display another random URL inside I frame.

```
<?php
$urls = array();
$divs[] = 'https://10beasts.com';
$divs[] = 'https://top5.com';
$divs[] = 'https://bestgolf.com';



echo '<iframe src="'. $divs[rnd(0, count($divs)-1)] .'" />';

?>
```

I have tried this code but it's throwing error.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function rnd() in /home3/user/iframe.domain.xyz/index.php:9

Comment: this is exact code which is throwing this error where line 9 is echo '<iframe src="'. $divs[rnd(0, count($divs)-1)] .'" />';

Comment: do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: nope i am newbie i am learning code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a function that isn't defined `rnd()`. It should be [`rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

```
echo '<iframe src="'. $divs[rand(0, count($divs)-1)] .'" />';
```